# Определение возраста сотрудников и обработка

Tags: python, массивы, файлы

Имеются сведения о датах рождения сотрудников учреждения.

а) Определите самого молодого сотрудника.

б) Определите самого старшего сотрудника.

в) Получите список всех сотрудников, родившихся весной.

мой код:

```
f=open('1.txt','rt')
q=f.read()
in_list=list(filter(lambda x: x != '', q.split('\n')))
out_list=[]
for string in in_list:
    item=list(map(int,string.split(' ')[2].split('.')))
    out_list.append(item)
print(out_list)
```

Дальше, я понимаю что нужно вычислить разницу между сегодняшней датой и датами рождения сотрудников -> наибольшее кол-во дней в разнице - старший сотрудник, наименьшее - младший. Но как это реализовать? Подскажите пожалуйста[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19OE3.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этих целей идеально подходит модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html).

Читаем CSV файл в Pandas DataFrame и парсим даты:

```
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas

fn = r'C:\temp\1.txt'

df = pd.read_csv(fn, delim_whitespace=True, header=None,
                 parse_dates=['DOB'],
                 names=['FirstName','LastName','DOB'])
```

получилось:

```
In [55]: df
Out[55]:
  FirstName LastName        DOB
0         А        Б 2001-06-23
1         В        Г 2000-11-13
2         Д        Е 2001-09-17
3         Ж        3 2002-04-07
4         И        К 2000-12-27
```

Определите самого молодого сотрудника

```
In [56]: df.nlargest(1, 'DOB')
Out[56]:
  FirstName LastName        DOB
3         Ж        3 2002-04-07
```

Определите самого старшего сотрудника

```
In [57]: df.nsmallest(1, 'DOB')
Out[57]:
  FirstName LastName        DOB
1         В        Г 2000-11-13
```

Получите список всех сотрудников, родившихся весной.

```
In [58]: df[df['DOB'].dt.month.between(3, 5)]
Out[58]:
  FirstName LastName        DOB
3         Ж        3 2002-04-07
```

---

Чтобы установить Pandas (при помощи `pip`):

```
pip install pandas
```

или при помощи `conda` (менеджер пакетов из дистрибутива `Anaconda`):

```
conda install pandas
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' как быть?

Comment: @Imao, дополнил ответ...

Comment: я могу с вами связаться,  в мессенджерах например?

Comment: @Imao, я пока морально не готов к такому тесному общению ;-)

Comment: у меня вопросы остались по поводу этой задачи. могу ли я их здесь озвучить?

Comment: @Imao, конечно, если уточнение то здесь, или открыть новый вопрос, если это "потянет" на полноценный вопрос / ответ...